# How to Select Class Below P Tag, Jquery Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used the below code on dev.tsecashmere.com for a tooltip hover from whoever previously created the site.

However, in the production version at tsecashmere.com, I can't seem to get rid of the `<p>` tags and therefore the tooltip is not working.

How do I select the welcome-msg below the `<p>` tag? or am I doing something else wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
<p><a class="welcome-msg" href="#">FREE SHIPPING &amp; GUARANTEED HOLIDAY DELIVERY</a></p>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('.welcome-msg').tooltip({
            tooltipClass: 'blueTooltip',
            content: function() {
            return '\<div style\=\"text-align:left\"\>\*Free ground shipping offer valid on all online purchases from November 29, 2013 through January 5, 2014. Offer not valid at TSE or TSE Factory stores. Valid on shipments to addresses in the continental US only. Offer does not apply to previous purchases.The last days to ship and ensure your order will arrive on or before Wednesday, Dec. 25 will depend on the shipping method selected.\<br \/\>\<br \/\> Standard Ground (3 to 7 Business Days) - order on or before 12/16/13\<br \/\>\n2nd Business Day  - order on or before 12/19/13\<br \/\>\nNext Business Day  - order on or before 12/20/13\<br \/\>\<br \/\>Guaranteed Holiday Delivery is available for orders shipped to locations within the continental/contiguous 48 US states. Delivery has been guaranteed from the shipping carrier which indicates a 12/25/13 delivery date.\<\/div\>';    
}
    });
});
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: Why are you escaping all those characters in the return string?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `.welcome-msg` will select the `<a>` elements, why do the `<p>` elements matter?

Comment: I'm new to jquery. That is what I'm asking. Do the elements matter?

Comment: @Barmar I forgot to preface. I'm a CSS/HTML person not jquery. This site was handed over to me by a client with no documentation.

I'm escaping all those characters to break up the text in the return string on [Free Shipping Text](http://dev.tsecashmere.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tooltip is not working because jQuery UI requires a title attribute, even if it's empty. Your jQuery code is selecting the `.welcome-msg` element fine but the tooltip itself is not applied. Change the HTML to this and it should work:

`<p><a class="welcome-msg" href="#" title="">FREE SHIPPING &amp; GUARANTEED HOLIDAY DELIVERY</a></p>`

Comment: that worked perfectly! Why did the version on dev.tsecashmere.com work without that?

Comment: Good question. Maybe there's an alternative way I'm not aware of but using ```title``` seems common.

Comment: By the way, feel free to select this as the answer if it helped you out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Enter your message in title=" /* Your Messge */ " attribute instead of writing a extra function.

It wil display your mesg.